# Using JPA2 to put data asynchronously to google datastore

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, jpa-2.0, datanucleus, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using JPA2 `@entity` to represent my models. I need to put data asynchronously to the datastore. How would I do that? If a JPA Dao cannot do that, can I use AsyncDatastoreService on JPA entities -- instead of JPQL? Does anyone have an example?

(I know in Python this would be a joke as I can extend `ndb.Model` to create models and then call put_async on them. But in Java there is no `ndb.Model` to extend so I am using JPA.)

Comment: Sorry, but 1) Why not just use Python? and 2) What does this have to do with Cloud Endpoints?

Comment: @bossylobster `Cloud Endpoints` is for perspective to the reader. Why java? I am learning because some employers (mine) developing mobile on app-engine don't use python.

Comment: @bossylobster it seems that you work for google. You don't like the java backend efforts such as GEP?

Comment: I like Java just fine, was just curious if you were familiar with Python why you wouldn't use it. I now understand.

Answer (score 1):

I am very much hoping not to have to use the following `ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread`. But so far it's all I have found. Does anyone else have something much simpler (like python's `put_async`)?

```
import com.google.appengine.api.ThreadManager;
import java.util.concurrent.AtomicLong;

AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

Thread thread = ThreadManager.createBackgroundThread(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      while (true) {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        Thread.sleep(10);
      }
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Interrupted in loop:", ex);
    }
  }
});
thread.start();
```